# Overriding 'dependency' files in maven

Tags: maven

I have a Maven project B that depends on Project A. Both create a JAR.
Project B creates a JAR with all the dependencies (code, resources, and JARs from A).

Project A has a resource called 'hibernate.cfg.xml'.
Project B also has the same file, 'hibernate.cfg.xml', but with different content.

Expected (wanted) result: B-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar should have B's hibernate.cfg.xm.

Actual result: It has A's version of hibernate.cfg.xml.

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: can we see your pom.xml, are you using parent-child relation or adding ProjectA as dependency

Comment: Adding ProjectA as a dependency